# Why doesn't my wordpress theme get the background images?

Tags: css, wordpress

This is the folder where I save my image:

```
 G:\xampp\htdocs\b2w\wp-content\themes\bootstrap-to-wordpress\image
```

in the stylesheet I write the code for background image like:

```
background: url('/wp-content/themes/bootstrap-to-wordpress/image/bg.jpg') 50% repeat fixed;
```

It doesn't work. I'm new to wordpress. Can anyone please help about what the wrong I'm doing here?

Comment: What is your wordpress url ?

Comment: Do you mean this?  http://localhost/b2w/

Comment: Yes ! When you go on http://localhost/b2w/wp-content/themes/bootstrap-to-wordpress/image/bg.jpg the image is displayed ?

Comment: Yes. it's displayed.I mean just a single image is displayed. I don't understand your correction. Can you be more specific please?

Comment: Your code should works. You can try here : https://jsfiddle.net/p63cbfog/

Answer (score 0):

I just read a lot in online and get the answer to my question. The answer is "I have to write my URL in the order as it starts from where my stylesheet is located. This is only for the background images."